# jQuery mobile does not hide the popup div

Tags: forms, html, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

I have a problem with jQuery mobile:

I have a sign in button, that should pop up the login form when clicked, but when the page is loaded the popup div is not hidden...

I tried about a hundred of different ways to let it hide (by adding some jQuery mobile attributes), but nothing would work.

the code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.js"></script>


<a href="#popupLogin" data-rel="popup" data-role="button" data-transition="pop" data-inline="true">Sign in</a>

<div data-role="popup" id="popupLogin" data-theme="a" data-overlay-theme="b" >
    <h3>Please sign in</h3>
    <label for="un">Username:</label>
    <input id="un" type="text" data-theme="a" placeholder="username" value="" name="user" />
    <label for="pw">Password:</label>
    <input id="pw" type="password" data-theme="a" placeholder="password" value="" name="pw">
    <div data-theme="b" aria-disabled="false">
</div>
```

Does someone know what i'm doing wrong?
thanks

Comment: Why didnt use display none property #popupLogin?

Comment: @ShibinRagh the jQuery mobile framework should autoinitialise this...  "This plugin will autoinitialize on any page that contains a div with the attribute data-role="popup"" --> http://jquerymobile.com/branches/popup-widget/docs/pages/popup/index.html

Comment: Please post a jsfiddle of your code.

Comment: here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/6EYst/

Comment: and this is where i got the info: http://jquerymobile.com/branches/popup-widget/docs/pages/popup/index.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

JQM 1.1.0 release has broken functionality regarding popup. you could try the git version (this is not recommended thought)

http://code.jquery.com/mobile/latest/jquery.mobile.min.js
http://code.jquery.com/mobile/latest/jquery.mobile.min.css